# rotated parabola passing over vertex and 2 points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have 3 2D points: the start, the middle and the end. I need to calculate parabola passing over these points where the middle one is its vertex (kind of a smooth route over them). I know about a simple 3 linear equations but I don't know how to constraint the middle point to be the vertex.

Comment: I won't make a full answer because right now I can't, but this is what I can put forward: if we were on 2D it would be easy to make a parabola go through the points. So find the plane that goes through the 3 points, make a change of coordinates, work on 2D and then go back to 3D. Another thing to note: do you really want a parabola or a curve that resembles a parabola? Because I am not really sure of whether you can turn any three points into a parabola with the middle point being necessarily the vertex. (If you don't need the middle point to be the vertex, then you can always do that)

Comment: The answers to the "possible duplicate" question seem to indicate that it is necessary to solve a cubic equation in order to identify the parabola you're looking for. But if you can assume the three points form an isosceles triangle with the vertex of the parabola opposite from the base (so that the triangle and the parabola have the same axis of symmetry) then the problem is much easier. Do you have any special properties like that that the three points might exhibit, or are they just three arbitrary points in the plane?

Comment: @DavidK: the points are the current position and two targets, the task is to get a smooth route passing the first and heading to the second. I think it's a parabola with vertex in the first target. It should be smooth because sharp turns are not possible (inertia). Or, in other words, it's route optimisation for minimum passing time (= max avg speed)

Comment: @RSerrao: sorry, I don't understand, it's already 2D

Comment: @DavidK: yes, the link sounds like exactly my question. The problem is that my level of maths knowledge is not sufficient to understand the answers. I hoped the problem can be quite typical for some kind of routing. What would be a proper name for it? Are there any existing solutions, e.g. a maths library or a framework with open-source code? I need to implement it for game AI

Comment: Now it sounds like you want a minimum-time curve for a "particle" (your vehicle) with some constraints on the forces that can act on the particle--foward, backward, or sideways relative to the direction of travel. The exact nature of those constraints can be important: an Asteroids-style spaceship optimizes very differently from a race car. Starting and ending speeds are important too. In any case I think it's unlikely that a single parabolic arc from point A through point B to point C is the best route.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered [here](https://casmusings.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/rotating-parabolas/).

Comment: As far as I can tell, that Web page never answered the question of how to find which of its infinite number of parabolas had a vertex exactly at one of the given points. I suppose it does at least give a partial solution, provided you are willing to use a computer algebra system.